# Graficar datos ya leidos de archivos .xls en html5

Tags: html5, excel, canvas

Este botón debe estar programado para que lea un archivo en Excel con dos columnas, la primera con datos(x) y la segunda con datos(y). los nuevos registros deben graficarse pero aun no lo he logrado.

```
var lineChartData = {
"datasets": [{
    "data": [
        "85",
        "87",
        "70",
        "80",
        "78",
        "100",],
        "pointStrokeColor": "#1A81C5",
        "fillColor": "rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.4)",
        "pointColor": "#1A81C5",
        "strokeColor": "#5D9CC6"
}],
    "labels": [
    "10",
    "20",
    "30",
    "40",
    "50",
    "60"],
};

var options = {showTooltips: true};

Chart.types.Line.extend({
name: "LineAlt",
highlightPoints: function(datasetIndex, pointIndexArray){
    var activePoints = [];
    var points = this.datasets[datasetIndex].points;
    for(i in pointIndexArray){
        if(points[pointIndexArray[i]]){
        activePoints.push(points[pointIndexArray[i]]);
      }
    }
    this.showTooltip(activePoints);
}
});

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).LineAlt(lineChartData, options);

var highlight = function(index){
myLine.highlightPoints(0, [index]);
}
$("#slider").slider({
max: lineChartData.datasets[0].data.length-1,
slide: function( event, ui ) { highlight(ui.value); },
});
```

El contenido del archivo Excel *al ser leído con el código que agrego en mi pregunta* es el siguiente:

[image: Resultados del Excel]

[DEMO AQUÍ](http://plnkr.co/edit/ARcJgvWoFyVhFkd3gnUT?p=preview)

Comment: El código que esta arriba es el que se usa para colocar en la gráfica y es independiente porque  lo que busco es que al ser leído el archivo de excel los datos obtenidos remplacen los que ya están para poder graficarlos, y aun no he podido hacerlo.

Comment: Comprendo, pero, ¿has logrado leer la información del archivo Excel? esto es clave para que otros usuarios puedan aportarte respuestas. _ya que un archivo Excel es mas complejo = no es como leer un archivo de texto_

Comment: El archivo de excel ya es leído porque al momento de hacer el upload del .xls sale de esta forma:

SHEET: Hoja1

columna1,columna2
2,7
3,6
4,4
5,3
6,6
7,4
8,7
lo cual lo demuestra, pero aun no logro capturar eso datos para graficarlos.

Comment: No puedo agregar imagen al comentario pero te dejo link de la imagen con los datos ya leidos
https://s17.postimg.org/mnt647wgv/Captura.png

Comment: En este caso, revisé de nuevo tu código, pero no logro entender cómo le pasas los valores leídos del Excel al objeto que requiere la gráfica; yo te sugiero actualizar el código para que "una vez leída la información del Excel" armes el objeto que requiere el gráfico, pero debes hacerlo en la función `function to_csv(workbook)`. Espero que alguien mas te pueda ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: en la linea 106 hasta la 117 del index esta ese código que me ha sugerido, ya de allí no se como capturar esos datos en variables para mandarlos a graficar.
disculpe si lo llego a incomodar es que este es mi primer proyecto y soy Newbie en esto

Comment: Te sugiero remover las líneas 111-112 "si no son útiles para tu programa".  Estaba intentando a partir del string armar un JSON, pero no he logrado el resultado esperado. Consulta esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16507222/4092887) para que te hagas una idea, colocaré mi respuesta _con código que no he probado aún_.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46439/discussion-between-jbs-and-mauricio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a todos por querer ayudarme, pero ya he logrado resolver hace varios días el problema que al momento de cargar el archivo de excel tomara esos datos y los graficara, dejare demo por si alguien lo llegase a necesitar más adelante.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmYfCjv6A8aE9zK7DIzW?p=preview)

Comment: dale brother! tienes madera para ser un buen desarrollador, sigue con todo el power 2.0! éxitos y bendiciones :D

Comment: Gracias y por si me surge alguna otra  duda, me verán nuevamente por acá!

Comment: de nada, esperamos verte colaborando con la comunidad :D

Answer (score 1):

has probado en usar las librerías **kendo**? A mí me funcionan de maravilla (sólo he hecho tablas pero se pueden hacer gráficos perfectamente).

Sólo debes tener un [dataSource()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) en formato json, te irá perfecto ya que el lineChartData ya lo podrá leer, sino usa algún parse.JSON().

Luego montas el kendoChart con [js](/questions/tagged/js) y lo ves en el `div` que hayas escogido. Siempre es mejor usar librerías si esas nos hacen el trabajo, tardaremos mucho menos.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<div id="chart" style="width: 350px; height: 250px;"></div>
<script>
var seriesData = [{
    date: new Date("2011/12/30"),
    value: 20
}, {
    date: new Date("2011/12/31"),
    value: 40
}, {
    date: new Date("2012/01/01"),
    value: 45
}, {
    date: new Date("2012/01/02"),
    value: 30
}, {
    date: new Date("2012/01/03"),
    value: 50
}];

$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        data: seriesData
    },
    series: [{
        type: "column",
        field: "value",
        categoryField: "date",
        aggregate: "sum"
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        baseUnit: "years"
    }
});
</script>
```

Aquí te dejo la **API** http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/overview

Answer (score 0):

Modifica tu lógica de la siguiente manera:

En este punto, ***asumo*** que puedes obtener la información en una variable cuyo valor sería así:

```
// Variables.
var contenido_excel = ""; // Contiene el la información del archivo Excel.
var arr_contenido_excel = ""; // arreglo de la variable "contenido_excel".
var valor = ""; // Valor individual leído en el ciclo "Ejemplo: 2,7"
var x_arreglo_grafica; // Contendrá la información que se usará para la gráfica (posición X).
var y_arreglo_grafica; // Contendrá la información que se usará para la gráfica (posición Y).

// Asignar valor a la variable.
contenido_excel = 
"SHEET: Hoja 1\n" + 
"\n" + 
"columna1,columna2\n"+
"2,7\n"+
"3,6\n"+
"4,4\n"+
"5,3\n"+
"6,6\n"+
"7,4\n"+
"8,7\n";

// Imprimir la información del archivo Excel.
console.log(contenido_excel);

// Estos son los resultados:
//SHEET: Hoja 1
//
//columna1,columna2
//2,7
//3,6
//4,4
//5,3
//6,6
//7,4
//8,7   

// Separa la información en un arreglo. 
arr_contenido_excel = contenido_excel.trim().split('\n');

// El resultado sería:  
console.log(arr_contenido_excel);
// ["SHEET: Hoja 1", "", "columna1,columna2", "2,7", "3,6", "4,4", "5,3", "6,6", "7,4", "8,7"]

// Recorrer el arreglo y obtener la información relevante para la gráfica.
for (var i = 0; i < arr_contenido_excel.length; i++) {
    // Solo vamos a obteneer la información relevante para la gráfica.
    if (arr_contenido_excel[i].trim() != "") {
        switch (i) {

            // Ignorar nombre de la hoja y encabezado
            // (a menos que lo necesites, modifica el código).
            case 0:
            case 2:
                break;

            // Obtener valores numéricos (según el arreglo).
            default:
                valor = arr_contenido_excel[i].trim();
                console.log(valor.toString());
                //x_arreglo_grafica.push(valor.toString().split(',')[0]);
                //y_arreglo_grafica.push(valor.toString().split(',')[1]);
                break;
        }
    }
}

// Final:
console.log(x_arreglo_grafica);
console.log(y_arreglo_grafica);

// A partir de este punto, ya podrías ir mirando cómo
// armar el objeto JSON requerido para la gráfica.
```

Comment: he estado remplazando el código que tengo por el que me has dejado y algo hago mal que no me corre el proyecto

Comment: @JBS, tu puedes actualizar tu pregunta.Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta con los errores obtenidos.

Comment: amigo de verdad no se que hacer con su código, donde colocarlo para editarlo y dejar funcionando la carga y graficacion del proyecto

Comment: @JBS, entonces, por favor devuelve los cambios, espero que tengas una copia de tu código antes de hacer los cambios; en [mi comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26273/graficar-datos-ya-leidos-de-archivos-xls-en-html5/26414?noredirect=1#comment43149_26273) te dije que mi respuesta incluía código que no había probado.

Comment: en eso si soy muy precavido porque hice una copia, aunque aun sigo con las ganas de resolver este problema que tengo aunque se que es fácil pero no logro terminarlo

Comment: @JBS te comprendo, pero, ayudaría muchísimo si puedes agregar mas información, así otros usuarios puedan aportar respuestas.

Comment: pues los que les necesito mostrar esta en el demo, y loque quiero hacer que al momento de cargar el excel lo grafique